# SwiftData Query sort of a property array of items by date

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I am learning SwiftData and would like to use it to convert my current app to use SwiftData. I am trying to construct a SwiftDate Query to sort an array of `Items` by date. The `Items` array is a property within the main model. All examples I have seen have a Query that uses the first level attribute to sort on (`@Query(sort: \TaskItem.name) var tasks: [TaskItem]`) but I am looking at a Query to sort on the second level (`TaskItems.items.date`). I am looking for help/direction. See my models below

```
@Model
final class TaskItems {
    @Attribute(.unique) var name: String
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
    var items: [Item]?
    
    init(name: String, items: [Item]? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.items = items
    }
}

@Model
final class Item {
    @Attribute(.unique) let id = UUID().uuidString
    var tag: String
    var date: Date
    
    init(tag: String, date: Date) {
        self.tag = tag
        self.date = date
    }
}
```

In my View, I have the main Query as

```
@Query var taskItems: [TaskItems]
```

and I am trying to display the `Items` which is a property of `TaskItems` sorted by the date.

Here is what I tried which I know is not right and does not compile.

```
@Query(FetchDescriptor<Item>(sortBy: [SortDescriptor(\TaskItems.items.date, order: .forward)])) var items: [Item]
```

Appreciate any direction/help

Comment: `@Query(FetchDescriptor<Item>(sortBy: [SortDescriptor(\Item.date, order: .forward)])) var items: [Item]` would be the correct way but you need a predicate as well to filter on TaskItems. In what context do you want to use the sorted Item array, is it in a different view from the `taskItems` or the same view?

Comment: I am using it in a different View called the ItemView where I am passing the specific TaskItem. For example, I am passing in taskItem[1]

Comment: Then use `taskItem.items.sorted(using: ...)` or `taskItem.items.sorted(by: ...)` in the ItemView, no need for a query.

Comment: I was doing what you suggested but the challenge is if I have large amount of data, it is slow. So, was wondering if I could construct a query to get the items sorted by date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this with a `@Query` you first need to update your models by fully defining the relationship between them.

- Add a reference to TaskItems in Item, the property needs to be optional since the other end is optional for the predicate to work

```
var task: TaskItems?
```

- Update the Relationship in TaskItems by defining what the inverse property is

```
@Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Item.task) 
var items: [Item]?
```

- Add the query to the sub-view

```
@Query(filter: Predicate<Item>.false) private var items: [Item]

init(task: TaskItems) {
    let id = task.persistentModelID
    let fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<Item>(predicate: #Predicate { $0.task?.persistentModelID == id},
                                                sortBy: [SortDescriptor(\.date, order: .forward)])
    _items = Query(fetchDescriptor)
 }
```