# SwiftData Predicate crash: can't use NULL on left hand side

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

Every time I run the predicate I get an error
xCode version 15.3
Destination macOS Sonoma, 14.4 
Swift 5

```
@AppStorage(UserDefaults.Constants.selectedFilterName) static var selectedFilterName: String?
@Query(filter: #Predicate<Filter> {
    $0.name == (selectedFilterName ?? "")
}) var selectedFilters: [Filter]
```

Model:

```
@Model
class Filter: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: String { name }
    let name: String
}
```

Stack:

```
can't use NULL on left hand side
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019c17eccc __exceptionPreprocess + 176
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000019bc66788 objc_exception_throw + 60
    2   CoreData                            0x00000001a29cb744 -[NSSQLGenerator newSQLStatementForRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:nestIsWhereScoped:requestContext:] + 4040
    3   CoreData                            0x00000001a29ca62c -[NSSQLiteAdapter newSelectStatementWithFetchRequestContext:ignoreInheritance:] + 140
    4   CoreData                            0x00000001a29ca564 -[NSSQLFetchRequestContext _createStatement] + 52
    5   CoreData                            0x00000001a29ca34c -[NSSQLFetchRequestContext fetchStatement] + 172
    6   CoreData                            0x00000001a29ca22c -[NSSQLFetchRequestContext executeRequestCore:] + 28
    7   CoreData                            0x00000001a29c9e94 -[NSSQLStoreRequestContext executeRequestUsingConnection:] + 300
    8   CoreData                            0x00000001a29c9bbc __52-[NSSQLDefaultConnectionManager handleStoreRequest:]_block_invoke + 60
```

Comment: Is Filter.name optional?

Comment: no, ```let name: String```

Comment: when your predicate depends on a property wrapped value usually you need to create use a false predicate and then set the real predicate that uses the value at top of `body`. That was the case for `@FetchRequest` I'm not certain for `@Query` though.

Comment: FetchRequest uses NSPredicates, that ask Filter to be inherited from NSObject and being NSManagedObject. I'd like to avoid this as I don't really understand how it would work with @Model :[ I'll try to set the real predicate in the body anyway but now without FetchRequest if it possible

Comment: You misunderstood what mahal meant, he was only comparing to FetchRequest not saying you should use it. You can not use anything related to Core Data when using SwiftData. I believe he meant you should do something similar to what I did in the last part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78168870/swiftdata-query-sort-of-a-property-array-of-items-by-date/78169428#78169428)

Comment: i tried this, doesn't help. Wait for a minute, I'll try your answer ```.onAppear {  selectedFilter = (try? modelContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Filter>(predicate: #Predicate<Filter> { $0.name == (selectedFilterName ?? "") })) ?? [])?.first }```

Comment: Thank you all! It helps, when I tried Joakim answer and set selectedFilterName to empty string before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JoakimDanielson and @malhal - thanks!
Answer is:
`@Query(filter: Predicate<Filter>.false) var selectedFilters: [Filter]`

```
init() {
    selectedFilterName = ""
    var fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<Filter>(predicate: #Predicate { $0.name == (selectedFilterName ?? "") })
    fetchDescriptor.fetchLimit = 1
    _filters = Query(fetchDescriptor)
}
```